# PHP session managment, is this ok to do?

Tags: php, session, isset

I have the following structure:

```
Index.php
Account.php
Login.php
CheckLogin.php
```

When someone logs in via login.php it checks the username and password and sets the following session variables

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

When they access Account.php
that includes the file CheckLogin.php which checks the HTTP_USER_AGENT and also if the username variable is set.

Now here's where I have the problem. If a user went back to index.php (home page) and is logged in I would like to display the account link.
However if the user is not logged in i.e. just visited the site I would like to show the sign up link.
I was thinking I could do the following:

```
<?php session_start()

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
// If username is not set destroy the session
session_destroy();
echo ("<a href=\"signup.php\">Sign up</a>");
}
else {
// If username is set
echo ("<a href=\"account.php\">Sign up</a>");
}
?>
```

I know this is not fully secure however if someone managed to hijack the session and went to account.php it would do the check which should destroy the session and log them out if they are not legit.
Is this best practice or is there a better way to achieve this desired result. I can't help thinking everyone just visiting the site and creating and destroying sessions is a bad idea. Is it the right thing to do or is there anything else I need to take into consideration?

Comment: Reading the code of an advanced framework and checking how they manage authentication would serve you well.

Comment: There are so many well thought through login systems out there for php, why not take advantage of one already done?

Comment: Just a tip: echo is not a function. Use echo "a", not echo("a"). No difference though.

Answer (score 0):

This is enough for checking. No need to destroy the session on every attempt.

```
<?php session_start()

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo ("<a href=\"account.php\">Sign up</a>");
}
else {
    // If username is not set
    echo ("<a href=\"signup.php\">Sign up</a>");
}
?>
```

If someone is able to hijack the session, he will also be able to access your `account.php`. As stated above, read a good tutorial on auth systems or use a plugin. Building an authentication without proper knowledge is a bit dangerous.

Comment: I was concerned that if I had lots of visitors to the site and it was creating a session and leaving that everytime someone accessed the page that it would not be good to do that. Should I not be concerned?

Comment: A lot of traffic is no security issue. The way your session handler is built might be.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials on authentication I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

if your checking is only based on session sure your website will not be secured. and I have a couple of suggestions:
1- use CSRF for more security on every post you have.
2- session should be always encrypted and you should use a salt key with them.
this way you can secure more. and just for information sessions is not always the best way to secure your website.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What is the way you would suggest for authentication?